# Leaflet Marker Cluster and Labels white hallow

Tags: leaflet

As you can see on my map. I have Clustered Markers and Individuals markers with some kind of white hallow around that I want to remove.

This is my CSS file for the style

[image]

```
.marker-cluster {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-radius: 1px;
    }
.marker-cluster div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;

    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font: 12px "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
.marker-cluster span {
    line-height: 30px;
    }
```

How do I revove this hallow?